# Error - running JGraphX Hello World example

Tags: java, exception, jgraphx

I get error message below when I run the HelloWorld.java example, out of JGraphX package.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=com/mxgraph/swing/mxGraphComponent, offset=6
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:275)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:69)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:540)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$300(URLClassLoader.java:79)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1038)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:429)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:660)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
>       at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
>       at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)

source code HelloWorld.java

```
package com.test.jgraphxdemo;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.mxgraph.swing.mxGraphComponent;
import com.mxgraph.view.mxGraph;

public class HelloWorld extends JFrame
{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -2707712944901661771L;

public HelloWorld()
{
    super("Hello, World!");

    mxGraph graph = new mxGraph();
    Object parent = graph.getDefaultParent();

    graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
    try
    {
        Object v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "Hello", 20, 20, 80,
                30);
        Object v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "World!", 240, 150,
                80, 30);
        graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "Edge", v1, v2);
    }
    finally
    {
        graph.getModel().endUpdate();
    }

    mxGraphComponent graphComponent = new mxGraphComponent(graph);
    getContentPane().add(graphComponent);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    HelloWorld frame = new HelloWorld();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 320);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

I am using Eclipse and **Java SE 6**.

**And it works well when i turn my jdk to 7. But According to jGraphx project doc [here](http://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx/blob/master/pom.xml), it should support compiler version 1.5 and above.**

```
<properties>
   <maven.compiler.source>1.5</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.5</maven.compiler.target>
   <maven.compiler.compilerVersion>1.5</maven.compiler.compilerVersion>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

I am totally in a mess now. Please help.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The library is built with JDK 7 by default. If you want support for an earlier Java version, just rebuild the library with the appropriate compliance flags.